# accordian, copy email addrress to each textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordian. And an email textfield. I want to copy the email address to each new textfield. But Now it only copies to the first textfield. And if I make a third textfield. It doesnt copy the email address from the first created textfield.

I have this:

```
// Add extra contact clicked?
$('#add-contact p a').click(function (e) {


// Make a copy of the first input fields
    html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();


// Get number of tabs in the accordion
    var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

// Remove the values
    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
    html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

// New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
    html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {


        me = $(this);
        attr = me.attr('id');
        number = attr.split('_')[2];
        newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
        newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
        me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);

    });

// Insert it at the end

    $('#accordion').append(html);
    $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');//Refresh!!!!

    $("#add-contact p a").each(function () {

        $("#contactpersonen_email1").val($("#contactpersonen_email").val());
    });

// Set last tab to active
    $("#accordion").accordion({active: index});

// Cancel the click
    return false;
});
```

and here I copy the email address:

```
$("#add-contact p a").each(function () {

    $("#contactpersonen_email1").val($("#contactpersonen_email").val());
});
```

But his copies only once. So from textfield 1 to textfield2. But then if I make a third textfied. It doesnt copy from textfield 1 to textfield3.

Thank you

I have this:

```
 <div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2 required contactpersonen_email1" id="contactpersonen_email1" name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: I thing change `id ="contactpersonen_email1"` into `class="contactpersonen_email1"`

Comment: I have that. See my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `$("#contactpersonen_email1")` will select the first item with this ID,

It should work right using classes instead of ids.

Like this :

`$(".contactpersonen_email1")`